# Significance of prostaglandins in semen?

Tags: endocrinology, embryology, reproductive-biology

I am trying to figure out how prostaglandins in the semen relate to the female reproductive tract.
More specifically,
How does prostaglandins in semen help the female reproductive tract increase the chance for fertilization?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. While writing out the question I found the answer on wikipedia.
Prostaglandin type PGF2α will act on the FP receptor to initiate uterus contraction which will help propel sperm further into the reproductive tract.